# Fonts not working in IE or Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I'm trying to get fonts to work in all browsers and I'm using existing code as this is someone else's project. I have no idea if they worked previously but the css for the font is written as:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'ChampagneLimousinesRegular';
    src: url('css/fonts/champagne__limousines-webfont.eot');
    src: url('css/fonts/champagne__limousines-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('css/fonts/champagne__limousines-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
    url('css/fonts/champagne__limousines-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('css/fonts/champagne__limousines-webfont.svg#ChampagneLimousinesRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

this shows up fine in chrome but no luck in firefox/IE.

Edit: The fonts work when uploaded to a server, but running on localhost doesn't let me see the font!

Comment: Did you include fonts files to the project ?

Comment: Do you see any error in your console - press f12 in Firefox.

Comment: All you need to know about CSS fonts is here: http://www.paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/

Comment: @Arun Nothing to do with css, just javascript errors of other stuff.

Comment: @Titus Firefox devtools do display CSS errors and warnings: press Ctrl+Shift+K and make sure that CSS filter on the top of the panel is on.

Comment: Make sure your server sends the right `Content-Type` response header when delivering the font resources, otherwise browsers might not "recognize" them as valid fonts.

Comment: @PavloMykhalov thank you - first step in the right direction, getting the error: downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "FontAwesome" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:2): bad URI or cross-site access not allowed
source: ...

Comment: Also, I've set 'access-allow-control-origin' and now the page hangs and can't load some resources